# HTML Biography Slider or Image Toggle hide/show onclick displays text

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I wanted to create a slider like this, but i dont know how to do it. Can anyone help even just on simple HTML? Thanks

Heres how i want to make it look like this.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery slider for div elements not just images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723835/jquery-slider-for-div-elements-not-just-images)

Comment: i think you question is asked before in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723835/jquery-slider-for-div-elements-not-just-images)

Comment: I just wanted to know how can i do this, even just a simple sample not as exact as on the image just the codes and format.

Comment: check this [slide](http://www.basic-slider.com/) from the post i mentioned earlier, It can slide images and or HTML content

Comment: I tried it already and its not working tho